# Эмпирическая функция распределения

Tags: python, scipy

В теме [построение дискретной эмпирической функции распределения (cdf)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1176215/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%8D%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-cdf) описывается как построить график эмпирической функции распределения. А как вывести еë формулу? Чтобы потом по подобранной функции распределения сделать генерацию новых значений (имитационное моделирование)?

Answer (score 1):

Выполняете приближение (аппроксимацию) своей функции и получаете формулу. Ее и используйте для генерации случайных чисел.

Хотя, конечно, это какой-то очень экзотический путь, и вообще-то не очень понятно, почему вы его выбрали. Но это уже за пределами вашего вопроса.